# main.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, angular14

I Migrated my angular application to angular 14 and update all the packages and dependencies, I am building my code and is is building successfully and also while running `ng serve` it is not showing any error.
But on browser is it showing error like this
[image]

```
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')
    at main.js:1:2247633
    at dt.exports.21 (main.js:1:2411389)
    at d (main.js:1:2195929)
    at main.js:1:2195963**
```

here is my package.json

```
 {
  "name": "lupita-portal",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "10": "^0.0.1",
    "-": "^0.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.8",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.8",
    "@angular/localize": "^14.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.8",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^6.0.10",
    "@ngx-i18nsupport/tooling": "^1.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/i18n-polyfill": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^8.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^3.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^7.1.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^7.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^7.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^5.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^7.4.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^9.0.5",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-label": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^7.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-menu": "^4.1.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^5.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-progressbar": "^3.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-sortable": "^2.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^7.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^5.0.0",
    "acorn": "^7.1.0",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^13.0.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^3.26.0",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "events": "^3.0.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "flexboxgrid": "^6.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^4.3.0",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.3",
    "openseadragon": "^3.1.0",
    "plotly.js": "^2.18.1",
    "plotly.js-cartesian-dist": "^1.50.1",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "ta-json": "^2.5.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tslib": "1.9.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.11",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.2.8",
    "@ngx-i18nsupport/ngx-i18nsupport": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^3.1.43",
    "@types/jasmine": "^4.3.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.9",
    "codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "^6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0",
    "tslint": "5.11.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: You might want to remove deps "10": "^0.0.1",
    "-": "^0.0.1",

Comment: Check all your libs. It's quite possible that if you haven't updated them they use a reference which is now outdated/moved. And yes, source maps will help you locate the problem source.

Answer (score 1):

You have a similar error with [`angular/angular` issue 50138](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/50138): yes, it is for a different property, with a different Angular version, but it illustrates how you would debug your issue.

First, make sure your `angular.json` snippet has source maps enabled:

```json
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "your-project": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "sourceMap": true
            ...
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, since the error stack trace you provided points to `main.js:1:2247633`, look into the source map to find exactly where this error is originating from in your source code.
You might come upon codes like [`packages/core/src/render3/interfaces/document.ts`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2419c486ad8a3129d27ade6852e33d1435512da1/packages/core/src/render3/interfaces/document.ts#L44-L56), which illustrates how a document can be undefined.

```js
export function getDocument(): Document {
  if (DOCUMENT !== undefined) {
    return DOCUMENT;
  } else if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
    return document;
  }
  // No "document" can be found. This should only happen if we are running ivy outside Angular and
  // the current platform is not a browser. Since this is not a supported scenario at the moment
  // this should not happen in Angular apps.
  // Once we support running ivy outside of Angular we will need to publish `setDocument()` as a
  // public API. Meanwhile we just return `undefined` and let the application fail.
  return undefined!;
}
```

See if your own code points toward a similar code.